# Light Detector/Identifier circuit using photodiodes

Tags: light, photodiode, phototransistor, light-sensor

I'm currently completing my final year project and am currently stuck going round in circles as how to complete it.

To summarise: I need to design a circuit which is capable of IDENTIFYING a light source (primarily biomass flame light) from other light sources using photodiodes.

My circuit will (hopefully) be in 3 parts. Part 1 - photodiode sensor circuit; part 2 - microchip to analyse part 1 and prepare results; part 3 - output results on display. Part 1 is causing me my problems as no one has done anything like this before from my research into this.

I have made a very simple Transimpedance Amplifier using a photodiode in photovoltaic mode feeding into an Op-Amp - basically a current-to-voltage converter. Howvever through exhaustive testing I have found that the circuit responds to any and all light and does not allow me to distinguish as to what the light source is therefore I stopped with this circuit.

My next port of call was to use the chip "TCS3200" as a standalone chip which has filters in front of the photodiodes. Connecting S0/S1/OE to 5V and monitor Pin6, I would measure light levels using the filters (Red, Green, Blue and Clear/No filter) to allow me to make an educated guess as to what the light source is based on the readings. I have yet to do this but will update this as soon as I have.

However my question is - is there ANY way that this could be done using photodiodes? Being able to not only detect light but more importantly to IDENTIFY it as well. Is there a way to do this? Have I overlooked something or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If color the only identifier you're working with or could you use other things like 'flickeryness' or whatever ... ?

Comment: Well I'm going with colour for now as that seems to be the best way to go - the human eye uses colour filters so I thought why not my circuit. I have no idea what you're on about regarding flickerness - please would you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: Have you tried using a prism to separate the light for you prior to analyzing it?

Comment: Yes, but I've decided not to for the following reason - I don't have much time left (got to be done in the next 3 months). Trying to get the angle right so that the light goes straight into the prism, and then the split light would need photodiodes in place exactly where the light could hit them is too much of a mechanical issue for me at this late stage - it'd just become another problem to add to the list.

Comment: TCS3200 seems like a good choice for measuring wavelength and intensity of incident light. Note the -OE pin is active-low, so connect it to GND to enable normal operation. [Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/TCS3200-E11.pdf)

Comment: Using a photodiode with a transimpedance amplifier is commonly used in SpO2 (blood oxygenation) sensors; the patient's finger is illuminated by a pair of LEDs, and by switching between red and infrared, the ratio of hemoglobin to oxyhemoglobin can be inferred. In this case, the photodiode only sees light emitted by one of the diodes, reflected through the patient's fingertip capillaries. But it sounds like in your case, you don't control the light source, so you do need multiple photodiodes with different color filters.

Comment: A limitation of TCS3200 compared with using a rotating prisim and optical slit to scan the spectrum, is you may not be able to detect the *spectral absorption lines*. That could be important if by "identify light" you mean you want to determine the *chemical composition* of the stuff emitting or reflecting the light. But if you just need to distinguish "the light is red" or "the light is green", TCS3200 will be fine.

Comment: MarkU - Thanks for your suggestions.
Yes on the TCS3200 OE will be connected to GND via a 10K pulldown. My bad. S0 and S1 will both go to 5V via 10K pullups, and S2 and S3 will have 10K pullups but also switches connected to GND so I can select different filters.
I had never heard of photodiodes being used in that way - but will make sure I look into it just in case there is something there to use.
Unfortunately I need to distinguish more than "the light is red" etc, I need to be able to say "the light is from the sun" or "the light is from a candle" or "the light is from a fluorescent tube"

Comment: Photodiodes come in a wide variety with different spectral response, depending on the material used to make them. By using some different types with their own amplifier, you can infer the characteristics of the impinging light to a reasonable degree of accuracy.

Comment: You need to fully define the wavelengths you want to detect and also define the wavelengths of the "other sources". If you don't reach this point nobody can help you.

Comment: @U5M4N8R candle flames can flicker quite a bit - the sun not so much ... that's what I'm on about ...

Comment: @U5M4N8R, brhans idea might be the way to go. A flame intensity will vary / flicker. You would need to amplify the signal, filter out mains frequencies - say a low-pass at 20 Hz - and block steady signals (the Sun) - say a high-pass at 1 Hz. If any AC gets through the filters you've got a flickering light which is either the flame or the Sun is about to go. brhans: Do you want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: Have you tried using diffraction grating and a camera? itll be pretty cheap like 6$ for the diffraction grating and then the camera

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the simple answer (photodiode(s) + a few filters) is no. Identifying flames requires a spectrometer, and even then not all flames can be identified. Google "flame spectroscopy". Some flames are characterized by narrow emission lines, but detecting these will require much finer wavelength discrimination than a few cheap filters will provide. The instrument you are looking for is a spectrometer.

If you can procure (borrow) one of these, you'll need to examine the particular biomass flames you're interested in to see if they have any distinguishing features, but be forewarned - some flames just look like blackbody emitters. On the other hand, neither sunlight not fluorescent tubes look exactly like blackbodies, so there is some hope for you.

Comment: Your 100% right on spectroscopy. If OP understands what spectrum he is looking for, it is possible he could use biased colored LEDs with additional selective light filters in front of them to absorb specific spectrum with something like ±20nm 3dB specificity. (Poor mans spectrometer) since he does not care about absolute signal accuracy.